# Input and output shapes in neural network mismacth

Tags: python

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YH1_BNbOaa8NHkZjsTNp79Ucux528bqn

i am getting wierd behaviour from the above code.
the output shape computed shows a batchsize of 2 while i am training one example at a time. on top of that , in my call method of my custom layer i have a weight matrix of [4000,10] so you would expect that the next layer should have 10 neurons. However the netork aparently performs a succesful fp even though i add more that one custo layer each with a matrix [4000,10] so each expecting input of [1,4000] rather than [1,10].

On top of that my compute_output_shape method doesnt seem to affect it as long as it is in the form (x,x) where both are the same number. please could you assist.

```
def call(self, y):

            self.y=y
            self.z=self.y

            self.z= tf.cast(self.z, tf.int32)
            self.z=tf.reshape(self.z,[1,4000])
            self.h= tf.constant([1,10], tf.int32)

            self.z=tf.tile(self.z,self.h)

            self.ks2 =  tf.Variable(tf.reshape((tf.gather((tf.reshape(self.ks, [-1])),(self.z))), (4000, 
                              10)),trainable=True)

            self._trainable_weights = [self.ks2]
            self.y= tf.cast(self.y, tf.float64)
            self.y=tf.reshape(self.y,[1,4000])





            return K.dot(self.y,self.ks2)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (200,200)
```